# Facing Problem in a simple contract

Tags: solidity, remix, transactions, tokens, solidity-0.8.x

I was following a course and wrote this same code from there.

Here I am facing issues while buying the token. As I have set the price to 1 ether I should be able to buy with ether but the moment I try to buy a token with ether It shows an error but when I buy with wei it works fine. What am I missing here?

````
contract owned {
   address owner;
   
   constructor(){
       owner = msg.sender;
   }

     modifier own () {
          require(msg.sender == owner , "ONLY OWNER CAN CREATE NEW TOKEN");
          _;
     }
}

contract TokenGeneration is owned{
     
     mapping(address => uint) public tokenBalance;
     
     
  
     uint tokenPrice = 1 ether;  

     constructor (){
           
           tokenBalance[msg.sender]= 100;

     }


     function createToken() public own {
        
         tokenBalance[owner]++;
     }

     function burnToken() public own {
          
          tokenBalance[owner]--;
     }

     function buyToken() public payable {
         require((tokenBalance[owner] * tokenPrice)/msg.value > 0,"NOT ENOUGH TOKEN");
         tokenBalance[owner] -= msg.value;
         tokenBalance[msg.sender] += msg.value;
     }

     function sendToken(address _to, uint amount) public {
         require(tokenBalance[msg.sender] >= amount , "NOT ENOUGH BALANCE");

        tokenBalance[msg.sender] -= amount; 
        tokenBalance[_to] += amount;
     }
}```
````

Comment: I am not able to add image........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are charging 1 wei for each token, and you only have 100 tokens in tokenBalance.
When you try to buy tokens with 1 ether, then you are trying to get `1000000000000000000` tokens, but you only have `100`, so it has to fail when you try to subtract the `msg.value` from the `tokenBalance` in the line:

```js
tokenBalance[owner] -= msg.value;
```

So, for you to solve this issue, you will need to create a lot more tokens in the constructor.

In the constructor, you can do something like:

```js
tokenBalance[msg.sender] = 1e18 * 100;
```

That way you get 100 units of 1e18 (1000000000000000000 * 100). You can now sell each token by 1 wei, and 1e18 tokens by 1e18 wei, which would be 1 eth by 1e18 tokens.

The `msg.value` is always represented as wei, so be careful with that.

If you really want to sell 1 token by 1 ether, then you will need to check if the `msg.value` is equal to `1 ether` and if so, then sell 1 token to that sender.

I recommend you sell tokens by wei and not by ether, since wei is more flexible to work with than ether.
This is also because you have a `payable` function and you are using the `msg.value`, and if you are selling 1 token by 1 ether, what happens if somebody sends you 3.5 ether? Will you sell 3.5 tokens? And those tokens be divided? Or will you sell 3 tokens and keep the extra 0.5 ether to yourself?

Refactoring your contract, this will work as you expect:

```js
contract TokenGeneration is owned{
     
     mapping(address => uint) public tokenBalance;
     
     uint public tokenPrice = 1 ether;  

     constructor (){
        tokenBalance[msg.sender] = 100;
     }


     function createToken() public own {
        
         tokenBalance[owner]++;
     }

     function burnToken() public own {
          
          tokenBalance[owner]--;
     }

     function buyToken() public payable {

         // Let's check how many ethers was sent. The msg.value is in wei, so,
         // dividing it by 1 ether will give us the count of ethers that was actually sent.
         uint countOfEthersToBuy = msg.value / tokenPrice; // or msg.value / 1 ether;

        // Make sure that at least 1 ether was sent, not less.
         require(countOfEthersToBuy > 0, "Not enough ethers was sent");

        // Make sure that whole ethers were sent, not 2.5 ethers, not 5.7 ethers,
        // since we are selling whole tokens, not fractions of tokens.
         uint remainingWei = msg.value % tokenPrice;

         require(remainingWei == 0, "Not whole ethers was sent");

         require(tokenBalance[owner] > countOfEthersToBuy,"NOT ENOUGH TOKEN");
         tokenBalance[owner] -= countOfEthersToBuy;
         tokenBalance[msg.sender] += countOfEthersToBuy;

     }

     function sendToken(address _to, uint amount) public {
         require(tokenBalance[msg.sender] >= amount , "NOT ENOUGH BALANCE");

        tokenBalance[msg.sender] -= amount; 
        tokenBalance[_to] += amount;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for answering But I have some confusion.
 As you mentioned I was charging 1 wei for one token but I set the token price to 1 ether.

Comment: @SolidityLearner, yes, `1 ether` is just sugar code. If you make the `tokenPrice` variable public and you take a look at its value, you will see it in wei, you will see `1000000000000000000`.

Comment: @SolidityLearner, I refactored your contract and included a better logic to be able to sell 1 token by 1 ether. Take a look.

Answer (score 3):

I found an another way to avoid error in this code.By updating the buyToken function a bit.

```
 function buyToken() public payable {
     require((tokenBalance[owner] * tokenPrice)/msg.value > 0,"NOT ENOUGH TOKEN");

     uint amountInEth = msg.value/1 ether;

     tokenBalance[owner] -= amountInEth;

     tokenBalance[msg.sender] += amountInEth;
 }
```

Comment: This is fine, but it's ignoring some extra wei that are not enough to be 1 ether. So if someone is sending you, for example, 4800000000000000000 weis, your function will only pick and sell 4000000000000000000 weis (4 ether) and keep the other 0.8 ether (800000000000000000 wei) to itself.
So, better check that it actually receives whole ether.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, It seems the idea of selling tokens with Wei is more suitable.